# Section of the Sheaf of Holomorphic Functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, blowup

I'm reading now the book "Vector Bundles on Complex Projective Spaces" from Okonek, Schneider and Spindler and I have an understanding problem with the interpretation of a section in following excerpt (see also page 18):

[image]

Here we take an open set $U \subset \mathbb{C}^2$ and consider the "$\sigma$-process" for $U$ in $0$, better known as a ***blow up*** in $0$:

$$V := \{(u:v,x,y) \in \mathbb{P}^1 \times U \vert xv = yu\}  \to U $$

Then the problem:

In the excerpt the authors introduce the section

$s \in H^0(V, \mathcal{O}_V ^{\oplus 2})$ by strange notation

$$s(u:v,x,y) = (u:v, x,x, (x,y))$$

My question is just what does $ (u:v, x,y, (x,y))$ here mean?

By definition, if $\mathcal{O}_V$ denotes the sheaf of holomorphic functions on $V$ then a section $s \in H^0(V, \mathcal{O}_V ^{\oplus 2})$ is a tuple $(s_1, s_2)$ where $s_i$ are holomorphic functions on $V$.

But I don't really understand the notation $s(u:v,x,y) = (u:v, x,y, (x,y))$.

Comment: They wrote $(u:v, x,y, (x,y))$ and not $(u:v, x,x, (x,y))$. It just means the section with value $(x,y)$ at the point $(u:v, x,y)$.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet: Yes, I fixed it. So it's a kind of graph notation for the section?

Comment: Yes, exactly. ${{}}$